can sqs receive message without consumer?
I'm recently using amazon sqs in my project.
my workflow goes like this.

service 'A' send message to fifo queue 'a'. service 'A' doesn't have a consumer.
service 'B' receive message from 'a' by consumer.
service 'B' send message to fifo queue 'b'.
service 'C' receive message from 'b' by consumer.
if error occurred while processing data in 'C', service 'C' send message to fifo queue 'b' again (with new duplicationId). step 3-5 loop until error not occurred.
service 'C' save data of message.

the problem is, sometimes queue 'a' receive message even the consumer is off.
when I'm running service 'C' only, sqs message sended to queue 'a' should be stay on 'Messages avaliable', am I right?
but sometimes the message goes to 'Messages in flight' when service 'B' is not running.
when I run service 'B' after seeing this, the service does not consume the message. It just get stuck.
Why am I having this problem??

What are your "consumers"? Are they programs you are running somewhere?

Are all the messages using the same MessageGroupId? If so, a FIFO queue will not provide another message while an earlier message is not processed.

@JohnRotenstein service B and C has their own producer and consumer in code. And yes, all the FIFO queue are using same MessageGroupId.

Additionally, I'm testing this in local. And Both services(B,C) use the same port, so they cannot be turned on locally at the same time. So, I'm testing each service by turning it off and on alternately. That's why I cannot understand how the message sended from C goes to 'Message in flight' even though the consumer in service B is turn off.
